# Echolocation System

Tags: lateral-thinking

I bought a device to map a set of caves, but I don't really know how it works. I pressed a button at a few spots in some of the caves, and it just printed out this gibberish:

[image: Square grid?]

I'm sure you'll be able to interpret this data to map out the caves we visited.
*(And find a hidden word in the process!)*

Comment: I think the first entry should be [(1,1),0N,2E,2S,0W] - see my answer. Please can you check?

Comment: @randal'thor of course you are correct, serves me right for writing puzzles at 10 at night... ^.^ Problem is fixed now.

Comment: And my solution now also edited!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Excellent question.

> On a 27-by-5 grid, draw arrows in the indicated directions from the indicated points (2 units south and 2 units east from the point (1,1), 1 unit east and 1 unit west from the point (2,3), and so on). The lines thus drawn spell out letters.

Here's a (not very good) picture to demonstrate the solution:

> [image: map]

The letters appearing are

> S, P, E, L, U, ~n, ~K

giving the word

> [SPELUNK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelunking).

Comment: @IanMacDonald Thanks for editing! There was a mistake in the OP originally, and once it was fixed I corrected my picture but forgot to change "west" to "east" in the first spoilertag.

Comment: I figured that was what happened. :)